# Use python's typing library to specify more than one possible type

Tags: python, function, data-structures, type-hinting

I want to specify a type hint for a function can receive either a `list` of `str`s or a `list` of `int`s. Is there a way to do this using Python? Something like:

```
from typing import List

def my_function(list_arg: List[str|int]):

    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Union` is intended precisely for this situation. It creates a new type that can be any of the types you specify:

```
from typing import Union, List
def my_function(list_arg: Union[List[str], List[int]]) -> None: ...
```

If you use it often, make a type alias:

```
MyList = Union[List[str], List[int]]
def my_function(list_arg: MyList) -> None: ...
```

I wouldn't recommend using a generic function as @user6269244 answer suggests unless you need it for some specific reason. Although `T = TypeVar('T', int, str)` will work in a simple case, it will be more restrictive.

For example, suppose you have something like this:

```
def apply_my_function(list_of_lists: List[MyList]) -> None:
  # each item in list_of_lists is either a List[int] or List[str]
  for arg in list_of_lists:
    my_function(arg)
```

In this code, you have no chioce: you need a `Union` (`List[List[T]]` won't let you store both a list of int and a list of str because `T` can't switch between `str` and `int` in the same expression).

But since you use `Union` in the code that calls `my_function`, you'll also have to use `Union` in the signature of `my_function` itself.

In addition, generics increase the complexity of the types, and at some point you will run into the limitations of the type system. So it's better to reserve generics for cases where you really need them, for example if you want the return type of `my_function` to depend on the argument type:

```
T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

# this can't be achieved with Union:
def my_function(list_arg: List[T]) -> T: ...
```

Comment: I guess this is more complete so I'm marking it correct for others but thanks @user6269244 - it solved the problem well enough for me before!

Answer (score -1):

```
from typing import TypeVar, List

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

def my_function(list_arg: List[T]):
...
```

Comment: This is actually correct, but only if there's a need for a generic function, which is not obvious from the question. For example, if you want to use `T` in the types of variables inside `my_function` or in the return type of `my_function`.